# Return string if QuerySet is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

In the following code, if the queryset is empty, I would like to return a string where the `results` field appears on the JSON response.

As is, I get an error saying `object of type 'Response' has no len()`. Does anyone know how to return a string in this instance?

Thank you!

```
class ProductListAPIView(CacheMixin, DefaultsMixin, FiltersMixin,
                         generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    search_fields = ('title', 'owner',)
    ordering_fields = ('created', 'modified', 'list_date_start',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        products = (Product.objects.select_related('owner')
                                   .prefetch_related('buyers'))
        for product in products:
            listuse_status_check.send(sender=product)
        queryset = products.filter(is_listed=True)
        if queryset:
            return queryset
        return RestResponse({'results': 'some string here.'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_queryset()` needs to return an actual queryset, hence the name.

You probably need to override the `list()` method, as described in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), so that it checks the queryset returned from the method and modifies the response accordingly.